Imported npm package module is undefined at runtime
I installed a package called "js-linq" (https://github.com/battousai999/js-linq) via npm install js-linq and it appeared to install correctly. This is explicitly in the documentation on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-linq).
I import it with the usual syntax import { Linq } from 'js-linq' and then try to use it in my React project according to the documentation: const items = Linq.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
There are no typescript errors or anything suggesting the import is bad.
But at runtime it fails, saying Linq is undefined.
What am I doing wrong here?

js-linq is CommonJS. I'm not sure where you got import { Linq } ... from but there's definitely no matching named export. Maybe try import { default as Linq } ..., but I'd guess there's also transpilation going on here.

@jonrsharpe: Your import default suggestion did in fact work! Can you write it as an answer, so I can accept it? An explanation of what this actually does would be really helpful too.

It seems like the types in this package in jslinq.ts don't match up with what's actually exported in the Javascript jslinq.js. You can get it to work as follows:
import Linq from 'js-linq'
console.log(Linq)
// doesn't work despite the types suggesting it should
// const items = new Linq.Linq([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

// this works
// @ts-ignore
const items = Linq.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
console.log(items.where((x) => x > 2).toArray()) // [3, 4, 5]



I don't see how that could change anything, because @ts-ignore isn't even seen by the browser, it just tells the IDE not to complain. I'm already using the Linq.from syntax and get this error.

Well, it works for me whereas the constructor method doesn't. I'm running it in node using tsx.
